# Chrome extension background doesn't send a fetch request

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension fires when a tab is opened, I tried it in tab with URL google.com.

In the `background.js` I send a fetch request.

I am getting an error:

```
background.js:3 POST chrome-extension://gbbpmoolodmhinpecafgjcbfnfcapoei/ net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
(anonymous) @ background.js:3
2_generated_background_page.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Here is the code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function () {
    fetch('/',{
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors', 
        cache: 'no-cache', 
        credentials: 'same-origin', 
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({"hello":"hello"}) 
      })
});
```

What is missing?

PS: the code seems to fire 3 times(the error shows it), why is it?

Comment: The background script runs in a hidden background page which has its own URL so your `/` is a relative URL that uses the background page URL as a base. It's unclear what you try to do here but take a look at the parameters of chrome.tabs.onUpdated in the documentation, it has the URL.

Comment: Also note that onUpdated is fired for all kind of changes in all tabs so this is probably not what you want. You can check for the presence of `url` in changedInfo, see the documentation.